# How can I use an array as an argument of a function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I want to use an array as an argument of a function. I expect that this is working:

```
function data($array){
    $pdo = Database::connect(); 
    $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM data ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
       $elements = implode($array);
       echo "Start> ".$elements. "<End";
    }
 }
 $array = array("$row['id']", "$row['name']", "$row['age']", "$someothervariable");      
 data($array);
```

But my result is: `Start> <End`

---

Edit:

Like this everything is working well:

```
    $pdo = Database::connect(); 
    $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM data ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
       echo $row['id'];
       echo $row['name'];
       echo $row['age'];
    }
```

Comment: Just do a `var_dump($array);` right after you define it and before you call your function...

Comment: @jeroen The result `array(3) { [0]=> string(12) "" [1]=> string(14) "" [2]=> string(14) "" }`

Comment: Are you expecting it to evaluate the expressions in the array like `$row['id']` when you do `implode($array)`? That's not how things work. It just combines the strings literally.

Comment: @Jarla just to be on the safe side, can you confirm that your database connection works inside your function? perhaps with a `try()catch()` block?

Comment: I don't know what php version you are on, but I would expect a parse error or 3 empty strings.

Comment: So many downvotes :'( I tried my best

Comment: @andrew: yes the database connection is definitely working well

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Sorry was just a writing mistake, updated my question

Comment: @Orions: I am expecting: array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "123" [1]=> string(4) "john" [2]=> string(2) "23"}

Comment: `$row` is undefined outside `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Orions: Yes, this is the main problem. So do you think there is a chance to create the array outside the function? Or is this impossible

Comment: @Orions: I cannot use it inside the function, because then I do not need a function anymore. This was the main reason to use a function

Comment: may be you need to edit question with full code and expected output and what error, output you are getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unclear what you are trying to do. Perhaps you want this:

```
function data($fields)
{
    $pdo = Database::connect(); 
    $sql = 'SELECT ' . implode(', ', $fields) . ' FROM data ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        echo implode(', ', $row);
    }
}
$fields = array('id', 'name', 'age');      
data($fields);
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you, nice solution! But for me unfortunately not working, because I need also other variables. Example: ` $array = array("$row['id']", "$row['name']", "$row['age']", "$someothervariable");  `

Comment: @Jarla Its not normal to pass full variable names to be resolved later. PHP supports it, but it's not something you see every day... I'd even say, if you need that, you are doing it wrong. Besides, any variable existing outside `data()` will be out of scope and vice-versa.

Comment: Ok, yes, I think you are right! I will look for a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function data($array){
    $pdo = Database::connect(); 
    $sql = 'SELECT  *  FROM data ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
       $elements = implode($array);
       echo $elements;
    } // this is end of foreach

} // you are missing this braces

 $array = array("$row['id']", "$row['name']", "$row['age']");      
 data($array);
```

working example : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20d306c8c7df9d4c446eebd34703a7fd68f76665

Comment: Oh actually, the missing brace was just missing in my question, in my code it is there, but still not working

Comment: my result is empty, in your example there is not a database connection, maybe there is the problem

Comment: try your database connection and query. If it wasn't a typo then your query **SELECT  *  FROM data BY id DESC** should be **SELECT  *  FROM data ORDER BY id DESC**

Comment: I edited my question to demonstrate that my database connection is working well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function data(&$array){ // note the & sign.
```